# Apache Ranger Row Level Filter Policy on Hive Tables

Tags: apache-ranger

I want to use wildcard in Apache Ranger Policy while applying row level filter policy. Since Apache Ranger have a constraint to use wild card what is the possible solution to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge when you apply row level filter policy on hive table you cannot use wildcards on it

Comment: Yes you are right which is why I am here to find out the alternative solution for this